# Wicket - Reusable panels with java inheritance

Tags: forms, inheritance, wicket, panel, reusability

1. I have following java classes:

   [image]
2. I have a two form components which are mapped to Type1Task and Type2Task with a CompoundPropertyModel:

[image]

**Problem: Duplicate Code. I want the D and E Fields to map to a task, not the task types. Is there any way to make this reusable when I hava java inheritance?**

If yes, can u provide me with tutorials or references?

Additional info: The task can contain a timer(thread). If you click on submit button the timer will be started.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the problem. But as an aside, if you're going to put your task objects in the model, they can't reference threads as model objects must be serializable.

Answer (score 6):

You can duplicate the same class hierarchy in the ui.

```java
public class TaskFormPanel<T extends Task> extends Panel {

public TaskFormPanel(String id, IModel<T> model)
     super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel(model));
     add(new TextField("d"));
     add(new TextField("e));
     add(new Button("submit) {
           (...)
     }
}

}


public class Task1FormPanel extends TaskFormPanel<Task1> {

public TaskFormPanel(String id, IModel<Task1> model)
     super(id, model);
     add(new TextField("a"));
     add(new TextField("b));
     add(new TextField("c"));
}

}


public class Task2FormPanel extends TaskFormPanel<Task2> {

public TaskFormPanel(String id, IModel<Task1> model)
     super(id, model);
     add(new TextField("x"));
     add(new TextField("y));
     add(new TextField("z"));
}

}
```

And the HTML files:

TaskFormPanel:

```xml
<wicket:panel> 
   <wicket:child/>
   <label>d</label> <input wicket:id="d">
   <label>e</label> <input wicket:id="e">
   <input type="submit" wicket:id="submit"/>
</wicket:panel>
```

Task1Panel.html:

```xml
<wicket:extend>
   <label>a</label> <input wicket:id="a">
   <label>b</label> <input wicket:id="b">
   <label>c</label> <input wicket:id="c">
</wicket:extend>
```

Task2Panel.html:

```xml
<wicket:extend>
   <label>x</label> <input wicket:id="x">
   <label>y</label> <input wicket:id="y">
   <label>z</label> <input wicket:id="z">
</wicket:extend>
```

Note: make sure you use some loadabledetachablemodel to wrap the task objects in if they contain a reference to a thread otherwise you will run into serialization issues. A singleton registry that stores your tasks and can return them by some random key is enough.

Comment: hmmm but there is a little problem... I have my form inside a Page, and there is already a <wicket:extend>. So I would have a <wicket:extend> inside another <wicket:extend>...

Comment: These are panels, not pages. You can add the appropriate panel inside the form. Panels have their own markup with their own markup inheritence hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. Once I works I will mark as answered.

Comment: Also read very important [note](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Markup+inheritance#Markupinheritance-UsingMarkupInheritancewithPanels) about inheritance in wicket panels (look for isTransparentResolver)

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class TaskPanel extends FormComponentPanel{

      private IModel<Task> taskModel;

      public TaskPanel(String id, IModel<Task> model){
      taskModel = model;
      add(new TextField("DTextField", new PropertyModel(taskModel, "D")));
      add(new TextField("ETextField", new PropertyModel(taskModel, "E")));
      }
}
```

Is this what you wanted, or didn't I understand correctly?