# Wicket - Reusable panels with java-subclasses

Tags: forms, wicket, panel, reusability, subclass

1. I have a java class:

```java
    public Task {

        private int id;
        private Company sender;
        private Company receiver;

        //Getter and Setter
        ...
    }
```

As you can see, I have 2 other custom classes in the task class. And a company has for example Adress and Directory (see screenshot below).

2. Now I have a form page with 2 sections (sender & receiver) representing a company. I don't want to make 2 seperate markups and java code for those 2 sections. Any way to avoid this duplication?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wicket - Reusable panels with java inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506698/wicket-reusable-panels-with-java-inheritance)

Comment: no, its different... here I just use subclasses which are not inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `CompanyPanel` which takes a `IModel<Company>`. You could use a PropertyModel on your task class to get one. `PropertyModel sender = new PropertyModel(myTask, "sender")`. The panel then can have two TextFields for which you can use a CompoundPropertyModel on the IModel that is passed.

Reuse this panel twice on your form.

On the CompanyPanel

```java
public class CompanyPanel extends Panel
{
    public CompanyPanel(String id, IModel<Company> model)
    {
        super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel(model));
        add( new TextField("address"));
        add( new TextField("directory"));
    }
}
```

Lookup the CompoundPropertyModel in the docs. It is really useful.

Comment: hmm alright.. so I give my CompanyPanel 2 parameters CompanyPanel(String id, IModel<Company> model) { ... }. Then I can use the model. But how exactly should a TextField be declared in the CompanyPanel?                                                   Now I have final TextField<String> adress = new TextField<String>("adress", new PropertyModel<String>(model.getObject(),"adress"));      So why using an additional compoundPropertyModel? Can u maybe give a short example...

Comment: Hmm... seems its not setting the values :(. I set the model and everything, but he gives me a NullPointerException, that the Company Adress was not set. In the Task Page I did as you said:   CompanyPanel sender = new CompanyPanel("senderPanel", new PropertyModel<Company>(task, "sender"));
  CompanyPanel receiver = new CompanyPanel("receiverPanel", new PropertyModel<Company>(task, "receiver"));

Comment: I want to use default values. Earlier I did: task.setSender(...) to set the inital default company. Maybe its because of that? I am using a dropdown list to set default values. How would I do it now with the panel?

Comment: Dave, better to read some more on models and how they work together with components. Default values can be supplied by just passing the correct default Company.

Answer (score 1):

Make a panel for editing the `Company` class and put two instances of it with different `Model`s to the TaskPanel

```java
public class TaskPanel extends Panel{

  public TaskPanel(String id, IModel<Task> model){
    super(id, model);
    add(new CompanyPanel("senderCompanyPanel", new PropertyModel(model, "sender")));
    add(new CompanyPanel("receiverCompanyPanel", new PropertyModel(model, "receiver")));
    ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Panel or Fragment, make its model a `IModel<Company>`, and add to your page two instances of it, one for `sender` and another for `receiver`.

- [Wicket Examples: Using Fragments](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/usingfragments.html)
- [Wicket Wiki: Fragment](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/fragment.html)
- [Wicket Wiki: Panel](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/panel.html)